# Wont log to console, javascript

Tags: javascript, console

I am having trouble writing to the console with the following code. Unsure as to why it is not working as am a beginner JavaScript programmer. May be a stupid question because I am new to JavaScript.

Javascript:

```
function process(){
    'use strict';
    var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;

    console.log(user);
};

function init(){
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('signUp').onsubmit = process;
};
window.onload = init;
```

html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Employee Register</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="post" id="signUp" class="form">
        <h1>Sign up.
            <span>Please complete all information.</span>           
        </h1>
        <label for="user">
            <span>Username:</span>
            <input type="text" name="user" id="user" required>
        </label>
        <label for="name">
            <span>Full Name:</span>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
        </label>
        <label for="email">
            <span>Email Address:</span>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
        </label>
        <label for="pass">
            <span>Password:</span>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" required>
        </label>
        <label for="age">
            <span>Age:</span>
            <input type="text" name="age" id="age" required>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
    </form>
    <div id="members" class="output">
        <h1>Registered Members</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="register.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/wz78j2p5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that the log is renewed for every request (in case of Chrome browser) and as you are setting the console.log to be fired onsubmit the log is logged but will be cleared immediately

Check the checkbox **Preserve Log** in the console of Chrome.

Comment: Thank you this is the correct answer, I understand what the problem was now.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the input type to a normal button to prevent the submit `<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">`.

After doing whatever you want with the fields you can submit the form with `signUp.submit()` or `document.getElementById('signUp').submit()`.

Comment: Forget to say that you will have to change the event. Use onclick instead of onsubmit.  <input type="button" onclick="process()" value="Submit" id="submit">

Comment: The problem I have with this method is that there is not form validation done this way unless I implement it within the JavaScript. Is there a way around this?

Comment: If you're worried about form validation before call submit() you can just do: `if(signUp.checkValidity())signUp.submit();`
You'll have to call submit() anyway doing it this way.